# Python tuple to json structure

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have in Python this dictionary:

```
[('157.55.39.64', 4), ('188.165.15.192', 2), ('1.165.15.192', 1)]
```

where the first field is an IP adress and the other one represents how many times is present in a file.

I would like to have a json representation of it like this one:

```
[{"ip":"157.55.39.64","times":4},
  {"ip":"188.165.15.192","times":2},
   {"ip":"1.165.15.192","times":1}]
```

I tried using jsonify(dictionary), but I get this:

```
{"157.55.39.64":4, "188.165.15.192": 2, "1.165.15.192":1}
```

which is only one json item. I don't know either how to put the strings "ip" and "times" in order to appear in the json file.

Any help?

Comment: Your initial structure is a list of tuples. Not a dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your original structure is called `ips`, you can get json you need with

```
ips = [('157.55.39.64', 4), ('188.165.15.192', 2), ('1.165.15.192', 1)]
json.dumps([{"ip": ip[0], "times": ip[1]} for ip in ips])
```

Output will be

```
[
    {
        "ip": "157.55.39.64",
        "times": 4
    },
    {
        "ip": "188.165.15.192",
        "times": 2
    },
    {
        "ip": "1.165.15.192",
        "times": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to convert the data into required format and the try `jsonify`.

```
data = [('157.55.39.64', 4), ('188.165.15.192', 2), ('1.165.15.192', 1)]
data = [{"ip": ip, "times": times} for ip, times in data]
```

Now, use `jsonify` to convert this list into `json`.